# Where can I find Windows 7 Gadgets?

Tags: webapp-rec

Microsoft used to provide Windows Desktop Gadgets on their [official website](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/personalize/gadgets). I can no more find those gadgets there, but only a limited number of them. Microsoft's explanation about the gadgets is as follows:

> Because we want to focus on the exciting possibilities of the newest
>   version of Windows, Microsoft no longer supports uploading new
>   gadgets. But that doesn't mean you can't still get gadgets. The most
>   popular and highest-rated gadgets are still available on this page.

What does this mean? There are only 30 gadgets on that page. Are the full list of downloadable gadgets gone for good? If so, where can I find Windows Gadgets outside microsoft.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the online copy of Microsoft's Sidebar Gadget Gallery. It is the best option for those searching for good old sidebar gadgets.

> **[gallery-live.com](http://gallery-live.com/)**
>   The Windows Live Gallery has been
>   retired - Here it is back again including all gadgets!

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is, Yes the full list is gone.

With the upcoming release of Windows 8 it seems Microsoft are shifting their focus on writing Apps (or gadgets) for Windows 8 rather than Windows 7.

I did find [this article](http://www.7tutorials.com/best-remaining-desktop-gadgets-windows-7) which lists a few more gadgets for Windows 7 that are still about elsewhere on the internet.

Incidently, a quick look at that Microsoft page on the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20110608224236/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/downloads/personalize/gadgets) displays a list of previously available gadgets. Unfortunately, the links are broken and all point to the current gadget page.

I wouldn't be surprised if Microsoft quietly pulls the plug on all Windows 7 gadgets once Windows 8 has been fully released.

Comment: They did the same thing for windows xp themes. I have the hardest time finding those things...

Answer (score 0):

I went through most all Win 7 gadgets on Microsoft's site a while back, my conclusion was that they weren't worth worrying about. They all tended to be clunky and poorly designed in my opinion. For any of the features I was looking to gadgets for I was able to find far better software app replacements.

For the basic gadget/widget like elemnets suchs as clocks, cpu, memory meters I'd look towards:
http://rainmeter.net/cms/
or
http://www.samurize.com/modules/news/

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is Elements Of Nature V1]

[image]

While it is not a Microsoft desktop gadget, Elements of Nature promises more than a simple  gadget.

It is an animated desktop weather widget that I created. It has voice weather description and can change the wallpaper of your desktop based on weather conditions.

Video presentation here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TqxNnVMsSss
Official website: http://www.stackoverphloo.com/products.html

You can download demo and install demo version for free. 
You can activate the full version for only 4 bucks via PayPal.

Comment: If this is your product, you need to disclose as such. See the [help/behavior] about self-promotion.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft turned off gadgets because they discovered a security breach with using them and they won't fix it because it is an old OS and not many people used them.

Comment: Do you have any evidence/reference for this?

Comment: Yes:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/security/advisory/2719662
and
http://www.pcworld.com/article/259085/microsoft_urges_users_to_shut_down_windows_gadgets_or_risk_attack.html