# Where can I download Windows 7 desktop gadgets (since MS shut gallery down)?

Tags: webapp-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find Windows 7 Gadgets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24648/where-can-i-find-windows-7-gadgets)

I wanted to download a *Google Calendar Gadget* for my Windows 7 PC.
To my disbelief, on the [Microsoft Windows Gadget Gallery](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/personalize/gadgets) I was greeted with this message:

> **Desktop gadgets:** Because we want to focus on the exciting possibilities
>   of the newest version of Windows, the Windows website no longer hosts
>   the gadget gallery.

I read this as: '*Because we want you to buy Windows 8, the ...*'.

Is there anywhere else I can simply download this calendar (and other) gadgets, without resorting to ad/malware/junk-infested torrent sites etc.?

[image: Microsoft message]

Comment: @Mepher: definitely duplicate. Can be closed as far as I am concerned.

Comment: More likely there was a big security hole in the Gadget code and they don't really want to go through all the trouble to try to fix it.

Comment: @AlEverett definitely a security Hole...http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2719662

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As linked in the comments above, you can sometimes download from the developer's site, however, I found this is rarely the case.
Personally, I'm a heavy user of I Forgot The Milk and the Google Calendar gadgets, and luckily you can still find both hosted on the [developer's site](http://scippleron.com/products.php).